# Modify actual code in program

Tags: c#

i have some variables in an app like :
 `public int temp = 10 ;`

Is there a way that i can modify my temp variable so that my temp variable will contain on restart of the app the last value that was stored in it ? I would like to do this without a config file.

(i.e. i would like at some point to modify my temp like : `temp = x;` where x is an integer and after i close my app and launch it again,the temp variable should contain `x` and not 10 )

Comment: And where would the value be stored while the app is not running, or the computer is restarted? You have limited options for persisting the value, it's either a file or a registry setting (or a remote computer, but that's another story)

Comment: And why would you want to do this? What is so distasteful about having a config file?

Comment: I was more curious than willing to do so, was a question that i had for a while and finally got the chance to ask it, being put in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend doing this for a production application but if it's just morbid curiosity then I suggest you have a read at this tutorial: [Modifying the IL at runtime](http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000058.html). It's not a tutorial that I've managed to get all the way through but a while back I was interested in playing with IL/CLR and tinkered with this.

Anything you want to use it for in production should persist in the variety of available storage options you can use: config files, database, file system, registry, etc. Modifying the executable is a *big* thing and shouldn't be considered lightly.

Answer (score 3):

Well it doesn't have to be a "config" file, but it's clearly got to persist the data somewhere. Modifying the executable itself seems a rather drastic approach, to be honest... common storage options include the file system and the registry... what are you trying to do that wouldn't be adequately solved with those more conventional approaches?

Comment: i am developing an WinForm app, and was hoping to avoid creating another file for only 4 integers that i need. Wasn't looking forward to moving that file after my program.

Comment: @Basescu: Copying another file is likely to be a *much* cleaner approach than trying to rewrite the executable. Especially as you won't be able to overwrite the file that's currently executing...

Answer (score 2):

You need to persist this value somewhere. Depending on the type of application you are developing (WinForms, ASP.NET, ...) this *somewhere* might vary. For example if this is a Windows application you could use the [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zszyc6e.aspx).

Comment: i am developing an WinForm app, and was hoping to avoid creating another file for only 4 integers. Wasn't looking forward to moving that file after my program. i'll look over Application Setting. Thanks

Comment: @Badescu Alexandru, using application settings is very easy in a Windows Application. All you have to do is use the Visual Studio Designer to add a settings file to your project which will create a strongly typed class which you could use to load and save values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Settings object in the application to handy read/store values

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a security reason for your question.
If you don't want to have the data on disk (even encrypted) and the computer would not be restarted, another process can hold the value for you.

There are many options for inter-process communication but you need to pass data encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for **Orthogonal Persistence**. There are very few programming languages that support such feature. And I think there is no mainstream languages that support Orthogonal Persistence. Ref: [Orthogonal Persistence article](http://tunes.org/wiki/orthogonal_20persistence.html).

For C#, you must at least use config files,registry, or database.